# stop focus on input range after choosing value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reset `focus` on `input range` after clicking and choosing range. How can I do that? At the moment i have to click outside input to loose focus on input.

```js
$('input').bind('mousemove', function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
  $('.show-input-value').text(value);

  if (!($("input").is(":focus"))) {
    $('.show-input-value').append('not focused');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="20"/>
<div class="show-input-value"></div>
```

Comment: Try `$('input').blur().focus()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('input').bind('mousemove', function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
              $('.show-input-value').text(value);
            });

            $( "#myInputID" ).mouseout(function() {
                $("#myInputID").blur();
                if (!($("input").is(":focus"))) {
                $('.show-input-value').append(' not focused');
              }
            });
        });
```

range field is

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="20" id="myInputID"/>
<div class="show-input-value"></div>
```